# What is `4` doing in this `memcy()` function in C++?

Tags: c++, memcpy

Below is a struct that I have and a variable of the type of this struct `RtpHeader`.

```
typedef struct _RTP_header
{
    unsigned char csrc : 4;
    unsigned char extension : 1;
    unsigned char padding : 1;
    unsigned char version : 2;
    unsigned char payload : 7;
    unsigned char marker : 1;
    unsigned short seq;
    unsigned int ts;
    unsigned int ssrc;
} RtpHeader;

RtpHeader rtp_header;
rtp_header.version = 2;
rtp_header.payload = 96;
rtp_header.marker = 1;
rtp_header.seq = 0;
rtp_header.ts = htonl(std_random_device());
rtp_header.ssrc = htonl(std_random_device());

std::shared_ptr<char> buf;
// binary data is assigned to the buf variable here... (out of scope of this question.


memcpy(buf.get() + 4, &rtp_header, 12);
```

I do understand what the `memcpy()` fuction does. But I don't understand what `+ 4` does here.

Comment: do you know what "pointer arithmetic" means?

Comment: do not trust this code. `buf.get() + 4` means that `std::shared_ptr<char>` is wrong. It should be `std::shared_ptr<char[]>` Anyway use of `memcpy` in C++ is considered bad practice. Also those magic numbers.

Comment: aside: since C++17, it should be `std::shared_ptr<char[]> buf;` (potentially a fixed size, but definitely an array

Comment: and "(out of scope of this question." -> no it is not out of scope

Comment: I first need to understand what it does so that I can use a better practice way. Why does it need to use `+4`?

Comment: " Why does it need to use +4" is something only you or the author of the code can know.

Comment: and you first need to understand what pointer arithmetic is ;)

Comment: So you omit the part where the `buf` is assigned some size, and then without us ever seeing it, want us to comment on why it must be skipped 4 bytes? No, this isn't how [SO] works. We don't do crystal ball debugging, we work with [mre]s.

Comment: It's `+ 4` because the code that uses the buffer expects the RTP header to be in that place.

Answer (score 0):

The `get()` function of the `std::shared_ptr` returns the raw pointer to the data object that it shared.
In this case it will point to the raw `char`.
The +4 simply moves an additional 4 char sized memory positions.
If the shared object were to be a `char[10]` buffer, it would point at the 5th element in that array, `buffer[4]`.

In your example there is no buffer, but a single char. In this case the result is undefined.